# Is there any difference between this two macros?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I find no difference between these two macros except the parentheses surrounding the macro in the first one.

Is it a matter of readability or is it a way to deal with the priority of operators?

```
#define TAM_ARRAY(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))
#define TAM_ARRAY2(a) sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)
```

Comment: `is it a way to deal with the priority of operators` Yes. A simple example is macros `#define sum(a,b) a + b`, which in code `sum(1, 2) * 3` will be translated to `1 + (2 * 3)`, not what most people would expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. The parentheses are needed so that the result of the macro is evaluated as a single expression, rather than being mixed with the surrounding context where the macro is used.

The output of this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAM_ARRAY(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))
#define TAM_ARRAY2(a) sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)

int main(void)
{
    int x[4];
    printf("%zu\n", 13 % TAM_ARRAY (x));
    printf("%zu\n", 13 % TAM_ARRAY2(x));
}
```

is, in a C implementation where `int` is four bytes:

```
1
3
```

because:

- `13 % TAM_ARRAY (x)` is replaced by `13 % (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x))`, which groups to `13 % (sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x))`, which evaluates to `13 % (16 / 4)`, then `13 % 4`, then `1`.
- `13 % TAM_ARRAY2(x)` is replaced by `13 % sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x)`, which groups to `(13 % sizeof(x)) / sizeof(*x)`, which evaluates to `(13 % 16) / 4`, then `13 / 4`, then `3`.

Along these lines, `TAM_ARRAY` would be better to include parentheses around the second instance of `a` as well:

```
#define TAM_ARRAY(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*(a)))
```

Comment: Your counter-example is so much more pertinent than mine :)

Comment: @chqrlie: Thanks. It could actually arise in practice, since there are times when keys are used to insert into arrays in a wrapped manner, so the index is calculated as a remainder of the key modulo array size. I just went to the C standard and hunted for the few operators that would demonstrate a problem.

Comment: Very good indeed. Do you have a non contrived example for `sizeof(*a)`?

Comment: @chqrlie: I do not see anything. The argument would have to include an operator with lower precedence than unary `*`, but, when the operand to any such operator is an array, it will be converted to a pointer, so `TAM_ARRAY` would not accomplish its purpose anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Macros are replaced textually in an early phase of code translation. Unless side effects are specifically expected, it is very important to fully parenthesize macro arguments in the macro expansion and the macro expansion itself if it is an expression.

In the case posted, you are unlikely to have a problem because few operators have higher precedence and they would probably not be used around the macro expansion, but here is a pathological example:

- `TAM_ARRAY(a)["abcd"]` expands to `(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))["abcd"]` whereas
- `TAM_ARRAY2(a)["abcd"]` expands to  `sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)["abcd"]` which is equivalent to `sizeof(a) / (sizeof(*a)["abcd"])`.

Note however that an operator with the same precedence placed before the macro expansion such as `%` would definitely cause problems as explained in Eric Postpischil's answer.

Note also that `a` should be parenthesized too:

```
#define TAM_ARRAY(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*(a)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The way macros work is that the code is "swapped out" when compiling.
So something like

```
#define ADD(i, j) i + j
int k = ADD(1, 2) * 3
```

would be seen as: `int k = 1 + (2 * 3)`

Whereas,

```
#define ADD(i, j) (i + j)
int k = ADD(1, 2) * 3
```

would be seen as: `int k = (1 + 2) * 3`

So, there are two macros likely because of operator priority.